# How can I reuse a JavaScript function many times in the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following code:

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
 var transition = 'slow';
 var target = $('#somediv');
 target.delay(5000).fadeIn();
 });
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="somediv">Some Content</div>
 <div id="second_div">Some second content</div>
 <div id="third_div">Some third content</div>
```

So as you can see the above function will work with #somediv but how do I reuse the same function for #second_div and #third_div?

I am new to Javascript so please pardon me if this is a stupid question. Thanks!

Comment: @zoltanToth thanks but the thing is i want to time each div separately...

Comment: While most people here discourage links to w3schools, I think you're at such an early level that you could benefit from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp). Once you think you know what you're doing, try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) instead as a more thorough and reliable reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a containing div, you could make a jquery selector like this to get all 3 divs

```
  <div id="somediv">Some Content</div>
  <div id="second_div">Some second content</div>
  <div id="third_div">Some third content</div>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
 var transition = 'slow';
 var target1 = $('#somediv');
 var target2 = $('#second_div');
 var target3 = $('#third_div');
 target1.delay(5000).fadeIn();
 target2.delay(target2Time).fadeIn();
 target3.delay(target3Time).fadeIn();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks but i want different time delay for different divs.

Comment: I see. In that case, you can just get all 3 separately and set them accordingly. See the edit I made.

Comment: @KPO You really should have put that in the original question, then.

Comment: Thanks @shredder! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    fade($("#yourElement"), 5000)
 });

 function fade(element, delay) {
     var transition = 'slow';
     var target = element;
     target.delay(delay).fadeIn();
 }
</script>
```

Then you can pass the object itself wherever you want, like:

```
fade($("#yourOtherElement"), 1000);
```

Note that you can pass different time delays, or can optionally even set a default time delay:

```
function fade(element, delay) {
    if(typeof delay === 'undefined') delay = 5000;

     var transition = 'slow';
     var target = element;
     target.delay(delay).fadeIn();
 }
```

Then if you wanna use the default time delay just pass the first argument:

```
fade($("#yourOtherElement")); //will have 5000ms as delay time
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use an argument:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```
function stuff(idstr) {
   var transition = 'slow';
   var target = $('#'+idstr);
   target.delay(5000).fadeIn();
};

$(function() {
   stuff('somediv');
   stuff('second_div');
   stuff('third_div');
});
```

If you want to change the timing delay, pass a second argument for that number:

```
function stuff(idstr, del) {
   var transition = 'slow';
   var target = $('#'+idstr);
   target.delay(del).fadeIn();
};

$(function() {
   stuff('somediv',5000);
   stuff('second_div',2000);
   stuff('third_div',3000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/cnH7d/

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it as you have it but it wouldn't work.  Besides changing the div# is there anything else that i have to modify for it to work on mine?

Answer (score 1):

Pass it in as a parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function divFunc(divId, timeDelay) {
        var transition = 'slow';
        var target = $("#" + divId);
        target.delay(timeDelay).fadeIn();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I ahve to use different time delay for different divs.

Comment: Thanks but I am a bit confused as to how to call the function for each div then.  Again I am sorry if this is obvious, i am a bit new to this.

Comment: When you want to call the function, just do: `divFunc('somediv', 3000);`, just replacing the div and the time with what you want. Call it for each div. When do you want to call this function?

Answer (score 1):

```
function fade(selector){
    var target = $(selector);
    target.delay(5000).fadeIn();
}
```

`fade('#div1') , fade('#div2')` you can pass any jquery selector as a input to this function to fade it.